# javascript how to use same random value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slickquiz

var myName = ['Beth', 'Chris', 'Carl', 'April', 'Cinnamon','Ethan'];

I want to be able to pick a number or name from an array and use that same value again? I am using javascript

Comment: Please provide your attempted code and describe what your challenge is with it so we can assist you in resolving that.

Comment: var randomVal = myName[Math.floor(Math.random() * myName.length) - 1 ];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use random Math function. If your array has 6 elements. you can use the below JavaScript.

```
myName[Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would something simple such as this not work. Up  to your to explore the truly "random" aspect of this but likely OK for most things.  Note that arrays are 0 based thus the `0,myName.length-1` parameters.

```js
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
var myName = ['Beth', 'Chris', 'Carl', 'April', 'Cinnamon','Ethan'];
var randomName = myName[randomIntFromInterval(0,myName.length-1)];
console.log(randomName);
```